# Sorting table columns in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter, angular-filters

The following code for sorting table columns doesn't work. I get an Error message:

> Error: $injector:unpr
>   Unknown Provider
>
> Unknown provider: orderbyFilterProvider <-

View:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('lname', reverse)">Lastname</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('fname', reverse)">Firstname</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('maxAge', reverse)">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (nameslist | orderBy:predicate)">
      <td>{{ item.lname }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.fname }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.maxAge }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ctrl:

```
//Get request to REST API
$scope.nameslist = resService.getAll();

//sort function
var orderby = $filter('orderby');

$scope.order = function (predicate, reverse) {
   $scope.nameslist = orderby($scope.nameslist, predicate, reverse);
};

/* default */
$scope.order('-maxAge', false);
```

resService:

```
...
return {
   getAll: function () {
      return requestService.name.query();
   },
...
}
```

How could I modify the sort function?

Comment: Please could you tell me if you remove all your filter and the code works, i.e <tr ng-repeat="item in nameslist "> works and then if you hardcode your filter to <tr ng-repeat="item in (nameslist | orderBy:'lname':true)"> and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Here what I have tried

Updated html.

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;predicate = 'lname'">Lastname</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;predicate = 'fname'">Firstname</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;predicate = 'maxAge '">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in nameslist | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
      <td>{{ item.lname }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.fname }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.maxAge }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>



app.controller("testCtrl",['$scope','$filter',function($scope,$filter){
        $scope.nameslist = [{maxAge :112,fname:'first1' ,MiddleName: 'middle1',lname:'last1'},
      {maxAge :15,fname:'first2' ,MiddleName: 'middle1',lname:'last1'},
      {maxAge :11,fname:'first3' ,MiddleName: 'middle2',lname:'last2'},
      {maxAge :14,fname:'first4' ,MiddleName: 'middle3',lname:'last1'}
      ];
```

There is no need of custom filter.

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CbH7dcrG7Z4D0ErtuL76?p=preview)

Comment: I think for larger applications I need to use a filter.

Comment: I think you have the order by spot on. I was mistaken in thinking I could pass the two arguments as one scope variable. Thanks!

Comment: with too much complicated conditions in filter you should use custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular's built in orderBy filter, like so for reversing as well:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="order('lname')">Lastname</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="order('fname')">Firstname</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="order('maxAge')">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in (nameslist | orderBy:predicate:reverse)">
      <td>{{ item.lname }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.fname }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.maxAge }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the following order function:

```
$scope.nameslist = [{maxAge :112,fname:'Amy' ,MiddleName: 'Sue',lname:'Test'},
  {maxAge :15,fname:'Chris' ,MiddleName: 'Deb',lname:'Something'},
  {maxAge :11,fname:'Sue' ,MiddleName: 'Amy',lname:'Abcd'},
  {maxAge :14,fname:'Debby' ,MiddleName: 'Chris',lname:'Try'}
  ];

//sort function
//var orderby = $filter('orderby');
// initializing the filter 
// if you don't want a default filter, you could initialize them to empty
$scope.predicate = 'lname'; 
$scope.reverse = false;

$scope.order = function (filterBy) {
   // if same filter is clicked again, and its not reverse then reverse
   // else just apply the filter
   if ($scope.predicate === filterBy) {
       $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
   } else {
       $scope.reverse = false;
   }
    $scope.predicate = filterBy;
};
```

The logic behind it is that sending an additional parameter true to the orderBy would reverse it, So we are just using this to reverse.

Also your error could have been because of this line:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (nameslist | orderBy:predicate)">
```

which should be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in (nameslist | orderBy:predicate:reverse)">
```

Here is the plunker that works:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JSoyoCkBwknlAggEwU59?p=preview

Comment: That is not correct. I'm getting the same error when I try `<tr ng-repeat="item in (nameslist | orderBy:predicate)">`

Comment: I have added a working plunker with my code. Is it possible that your result itself is not getting displayed?