# Order by Angular

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have problem with sorting data. I get data from JSON. Then, by certain formulas, I get results and sort them. I have a problem with sorting, I need each column to click to sort, but at one time I do not sort it

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<table border="0" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="sortBy('session')">TYPE</th>
        <th>HEIGHT</th>
        <th>TIME</th>
        <th>DISTANCE</th>
        <tr ng-repeat="y in playerStatisticSession|orderBy:heartrate">
            <td ng-if="sendParams() == y.player_id">{{y.type}}</td>
            <td ng-if="sendParams() == y.player_id">{{getHeight(y.player_id) | number: 2}}</td>
            <td ng-if="sendParams() == y.player_id">*****</td>
            <td ng-if="sendParams() == y.player_id">{{getMaxDistance(y.player_id, y.table_activity_ID) / x.max * 100 | number:2}}% ({{getMaxDistance(y.player_id,
                y.table_activity_ID)}})
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/api/playerStatisticSession")
.then(function successCallback(response) {
console.log("/playerStatisticSession")
$scope.playerStatisticSession = response.data.playerStatisticSession;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
console.log("Error!");
});

$scope.propertyName = 'session';
$scope.reverse = false;
$scope.sessions = orderBy($scope.propertyName, $scope.reverse);

$scope.sortBy = function (propertyName) {
$scope.reverse = (propertyName !== null && $scope.propertyName === 
propertyName)
    ? !$scope.reverse : false;
$scope.propertyName = propertyName;
$scope.sessions = orderBy($scope.propertyName, $scope.reverse);
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting table columns in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074421/sorting-table-columns-in-angularjs)

Comment: you need to add quote around 'heartrate'.